# Jquerymobile page content save in database and retrieve it on same format

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My requirement is the user will edit the content of template in a separate editor
after clicking an edit button in template. After that the modified content will get saved into database.

According to defined example:
I had create a button dynamically  on screen and change it at run-time and that save the 
content in database but after that when i open it in EDIT mode its
shown its enhanced JQM insted what i saved.
Please provide me a actual way to save a same content in database.

```
enter code here :Im trying to save - <a href="#somelink" data-role="button" data-icon="hello">Button</a>


its shown in EDIT mode : <a class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a" data-icon="hello" data-iconpos="left" data-role="button" href="#somelink" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a">
 <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
     <span class="ui-btn-text">Button</span>
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-hello ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
 </span>
```

I am trying to listening for the pagecreate or pageinit event.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap your `Edit` box in a container with `data-enhance="false"`

Refer to the `Enhancement` section in [JQueryMobile Data Attributes Reference Page.](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/data-attributes.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply,I appriciate it. But,this is not a way that i followed,Actually my requirement is the user will edit the content of template in a separate editor after clicking an edit button in template. After that the modified content will get saved into database. or According to your defined example: I had create a button dynamically on screen and change it at run-time and that save the content in database but after that when i open it in EDIT mode its shown its enhanced JQM insted what i saved. Please provide me a actual way to save a same content in database. Thanks